# Calling REST API gives error TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am trying to call REST API and it's throwing error as below

```
[Show/hide message details.] TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
```

I am new to REST APIs.

My API structure looks like this

```
{
    "Agents":
    {
        "@ZipCode": "33176",
        "Agent": [
        {
            "AgencyID": "21",
            "Name": "Anakarina Callejas",
            "Phone": "305-515-5613",
            "CityName": "KENDALL",
            "Address": "10471 N Kendall Dr. #101. Miami, FL 33176",
            "Reviews-Rating": "5",
            "Reviews-Count": "74",
            "image": "/images/agents/21.png"
        },
        {
            "AgencyID": "116",
            "Name": "Tamara Mourino",
            "Phone": "305-256-0616",
            "CityName": "PINECREST",
            "Address": "12745 South Dixie Highway. #101. Pinecrest, FL 33156",
            "Reviews-Rating": "5",
            "Reviews-Count": "70",
            "image": "/images/agents/116.png"
        }]
    }
}
```

amd my API call is like this

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'URL to the API', true);

request.onload = function () {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

  data.forEach(agent => {
    console.log(agent.Name);
  });
}

request.send();
```

Comment: Your `data` is an object not an array, the only array in your returned response is `Agent` which with your structure would be at `data.Agents.Agent`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Your API Structure it looks that your  `data` is an `object` not an `array`.

Firstly get the `Agent array` from the `data` object then iterate over it to get `name` of each `Agent`.

```
var responseData =JSON.parse(responseData);
var data= responseData.Agents.Agent;
data.forEach(agent => {
    console.log(agent.Name);
  });
```

**Snippet with your sample Data:**

```js
var responseData='{"Agents":{"@ZipCode": "33176","Agent": [{"AgencyID": "21","Name": "Anakarina Callejas","Phone": "305-515-5613","CityName": "KENDALL","Address": "10471 N Kendall Dr. #101. Miami, FL 33176","Reviews-Rating": "5","Reviews-Count": "74","image": "/images/agents/21.png"},{"AgencyID": "116","Name": "Tamara Mourino","Phone": "305-256-0616","CityName": "PINECREST","Address": "12745 South Dixie Highway. #101. Pinecrest, FL 33156","Reviews-Rating": "5","Reviews-Count": "70","image": "/images/agents/116.png"}]}}';
var responseData =JSON.parse(responseData);
var data= responseData.Agents.Agent;
data.forEach(agent => {
    console.log(agent.Name);
});
```

Comment: this helped, thank you. however i would split the data variable like this   `var responseData = JSON.parse(this.response);
       var data = responseData.Agents.Agent;`

Comment: hi, i have another problem as well, could you look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51902982/5653071