# call rest api and display result as searched for

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am calling a `REST API` from this `HTML` form

```
<form action="#">
    <h1>Enter your zip code</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip">
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="callREST()">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My API structure looks like this

```
{
    "Agents":
    {
        "@ZipCode": "33176",
        "Agent": [
        {
            "AgencyID": "21",
            "Name": "Anakarina Callejas",
            "Phone": "305-515-5613",
            "CityName": "KENDALL",
            "Address": "10471 N Kendall Dr. #101. Miami, FL 33176",
            "Reviews-Rating": "5",
            "Reviews-Count": "74",
            "image": "/images/agents/21.png"
        },
        {
            "AgencyID": "116",
            "Name": "Tamara Mourino",
            "Phone": "305-256-0616",
            "CityName": "PINECREST",
            "Address": "12745 South Dixie Highway. #101. Pinecrest, FL 33156",
            "Reviews-Rating": "5",
            "Reviews-Count": "70",
            "image": "/images/agents/116.png"
        }]
    }
}
```

and this is how i am calling the API

```
function callREST() {
    // Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
    request.open('GET', 'URL to the API', true);

    request.onload = function () {
      // Begin accessing JSON data here
      var responseData = JSON.parse(this.response);
      var data = responseData.Agents.Agent;

      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        data.forEach(agent => {
          // Log each agent's title
          console.log(agent.Name);
        });
      } else {
          console.log('error');
        }

    }

    // Send request
    request.send();
}
```

I get all the data but what i need is only the data that matches the `ZIP Code` entered in the `input field`

Comment: `Agents` is an object or Array?

Comment: Write if condition for Zip Code.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz it should be an object

Comment: @ShakeerHussain but how do i get Zip Code in the first place? I am very new to REST API so anything you help me with would be appreciated.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz you'll notice `Agents` is object and `Agent` has array

Comment: ZipCode is part of `Agents` object while you data is in `Agent` array?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz that's correct

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz and that's the problem i am facing

Comment: So there will be only single object Agents with key ZipCode so what the problem, use if statement

Comment: this is just an example api, so the case could be there are 2 or more ZipCode

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz am i clear to you or still confusing? i am so new and might confuse you as well. sorry if i did

Comment: Look at your code `responseData.Agents.Agent` responseData is an object, Agents is an object, how there can be multiple Agents objects in an object. Or even how can be multiple ZipCode prpertirs in Agents object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178227/discussion-between-lucian-and-zohaib-ijaz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get **@ZipCode** value from `Agents` object and compare with the `input value`.

```
var responseData =JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
var zipCode= responseData.Agents['@ZipCode'];
```

Here is the working snippet that display the `alert` if `input value` is matched with sample data' `zipCode` value.

```js
  var jsonResponse='{"Agents":{"@ZipCode": "33176","Agent": [{"AgencyID": "21","Name": "Anakarina Callejas","Phone": "305-515-5613","CityName": "KENDALL","Address": "10471 N Kendall Dr. #101. Miami, FL 33176","Reviews-Rating": "5","Reviews-Count": "74","image": "/images/agents/21.png"},{"AgencyID": "116","Name": "Tamara Mourino","Phone": "305-256-0616","CityName": "PINECREST","Address": "12745 South Dixie Highway. #101. Pinecrest, FL 33156","Reviews-Rating": "5","Reviews-Count": "70","image": "/images/agents/116.png"}]}}';

function callREST() {
   event.preventDefault();//for demo to prevent form submit.
   var inputZip=document.getElementById("zip").value;
   var responseData =JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
   var zipCode= responseData.Agents['@ZipCode'];
   //console.log(inputZip,zipCode);
   if(zipCode==inputZip){
      alert("ZipCode matched.");
   }else{
     alert("ZipCode not matched.");
   }
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <h1>Enter your zip code</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip">
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="callREST();">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Note:** From comments it is still confusing that how your `response` object can have **multiple zipCode**.

> **@Comment-** Look at your code responseData.Agents.Agent responseData is an object, Agents is an object, how there can be multiple Agents objects in an object. Or even how can be multiple ZipCode prpertirs in Agents object